# Take the user name from the URL and redirect with a query string with that user name

Tags: javascript, asp.net, url, redirect, server

I want to implement a jquery script that takes any name after the slash "/" in a domain address and redirect the user to the default page with a querystring with the user name. For example if a user writes mydomain.com/username, I want to redirect the page to mydomain.com/default.aspx?name=username.

How can I accomplish that?
Thanks

SOLUTION

I added the following code in the global.asa file.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Uri uriAddress = new Uri(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);

        if (uriAddress.Segments != null && uriAddress.Segments.Length > 1 && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(uriAddress.Segments[1]))
        {
            string SegmentUsername = uriAddress.Segments[1];
            Response.Redirect("default.aspx?name=" + SegmentUsername);                
        } 
    }
```

Comment: You should do this on server side (parsing URL, redirecting and so on). JS and jQuery are not relevant to described situation.

Comment: i think doing this from server side is best practice.. probabbly you need to do it with URL rewriting..

Answer (score 0):

here it is a complete solution against URL Rewriting..
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/641758/An-Example-of-URL-Rewriting-With-ASP-NET

text from there..
URL rewriting is the process of intercepting an incoming Web request and redirecting the request to a different resource. When performing URL rewriting, typically the URL being requested is checked and, based on its value, the request is redirected to a different URL. For example, a website restructuring web pages of a specified directory or article and when accessing a web page from an article or directory by URL then the URL is automatically moved on to the Blog directory. That happens by URL rewriting.

Comment: Is there any straight forward documentation about my case? Never worked with URL trimming, parsing....etc

Answer (score 0):

here is a typical example which will work in your specific case..
and let you know how URL rewriting works..

add this class in your asp.net website  App_code folder

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Class1
/// </summary>
 public class URLRule
    {
        public string URLPateren { set; get; }
        public string Rewrite { set; get; }
    }
    public class ListURL : List<URLRule>
    {

        public ListURL()
        {
            //may be you need to redefine this rule in order to make it mature.
            URLRule obj = new URLRule();
            obj.URLPateren = "/(.*)?/(.*)";
            obj.Rewrite = "default.aspx?name=$2";
            Add(obj);
            //here you can add more rules as above..

        }

        public string Process(string str)
        {

            Regex oReg;

            foreach (URLRule obj in this)
            {
                oReg = new Regex(obj.URLPateren);
                Match oMatch = oReg.Match(str);

                if (oMatch.Success)
                {
                    string s = oReg.Replace(str, obj.Rewrite);
                    return s;
                }
            }
            return str;
        }
    }
```

now add this following  piece of code in your global.asax 
if you do not already have then add it from adding new item then select "global application class"

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        ListURL rewriter = new ListURL();

        string re = rewriter.Process(Request.Path);
        if (Request.Path != re)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(re);
        }



    }
```

and here you can check your query string value at default.aspx page's load event.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString.HasKeys()) {
            string queryvalue = Request.QueryString["name"];
            Response.Write("User Name : " + queryvalue);

        }
    }
```

i tried this url and working fine..

**localhost:3030/WebSite3/xyz123**

if it does not work or having url pattern changed then try to redefine URLRule.
here "xyz123" is name.
I hope it works...